# Array Exploding issues

Tags: php

All exparts I facing issue with Array Exploding

data.txt content is below

```
Peer             Call ID      Duration Recv: Pack  Lost       (     %) Jitter Send: Pack  Lost       (     %) Jitter
139.59.232.196   0bb9262d6a1  00:01:12 0000003558  0000000000 ( 0.00%) 0.0000 0000001177  0000000000 ( 0.00%) 0.0200
139.59.232.196   41283499492  00:00:00 0000000000  0000000000 ( 0.00%) 0.0000 0000000000  0000000000 ( 0.00%) 0.0000
139.59.232.196   7033a541240  00:00:08 0000000000  0000000000 ( 0.00%) 0.0000 0000000019  0000000000 ( 0.00%) 0.0000
3 active SIP channels
```

PHP Code is Below

```
$heads = [ 'Peer', 0, 0, 'CallId', 0, 'Duration', 'Recv', 0, 'RecvLost', 0, 'RecvPC', 'RJitter', 'Send', 0, 'SendLost', 0, 'SendPC', 'SJitter'];

$data = file('data.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
unset($data[0]); // Lose heading line

$list = [];
foreach ($data as $str) {
    $list[] = array_combine($heads, explode(' ',$str));
}
```

print_r($list); out put below somethings like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Peer] => 139.59.232.196
            [0] => (
            [CallId] => 0bb9262d6a1
            [Duration] => 00:01:12
            [Recv] => 0000003558
            [RecvLost] => 0000000000
            [RecvPC] => 0.00%)
            [RJitter] => 0.0000
            [Send] => 0000001177
            [SendLost] => 0000000000
            [SendPC] => 0.00%)
            [SJitter] => 0.0200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Peer] => 139.59.232.196
            [0] => (
            [CallId] => 41283499492
            [Duration] => 00:00:00
            [Recv] => 0000000000
            [RecvLost] => 0000000000
            [RecvPC] => 0.00%)
            [RJitter] => 0.0000
            [Send] => 0000000000
            [SendLost] => 0000000000
            [SendPC] => 0.00%)
            [SJitter] => 0.0000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Peer] => 139.59.232.196
            [0] => (
            [CallId] => 7033a541240
            [Duration] => 00:00:08
            [Recv] => 0000000000
            [RecvLost] => 0000000000
            [RecvPC] => 0.00%)
            [RJitter] => 0.0000
            [Send] => 0000000019
            [SendLost] => 0000000000
            [SendPC] => 0.00%)
            [SJitter] => 0.0000
        )

)
```

when I called them I have to do like this, $list['0'][Duration] then it's giving Array 0 Duration field data, but I want when I called like this $list[Duration] it will give me all Array Duration data like below

```
00:01:12 00:00:00 00:00:08
```

Thanks for your attention...

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you mean, but are you looking for [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)?

Comment: What have you tried? unfortunately StackOverflow is not a free code writing service for you

Comment: Dear, Martin I know very very well fully StackOverflow is not a free code writing for me, I won't have to learn from you & with respect, I am suggesting you respect the newcomer, we are learner not stupid! hope you will behave yourself, I share my current code that means I haven't asked for writing code for me, anyway forget it in the world there is lots of people like your type but also a lot of people other type who love to share knowledge & teach or help others, so please I request to you keep your nasty behaviour on yourself not need to show in forum. Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You need [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function:

```
$durations = array_column($list, 'Duration');
```

For php **older** than `5.5` you will need a simple `foreach`.